# Database table design confusion in Django

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

**System overview:**

In my system, client can sign up for the application, then the client can create a role and create users with the role defined. Thus, one client can have many users.

I have create a client model which is related to user.

```
class Client(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # True if the signed up user is client
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=True)   

    # Which company the client represents
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    # Address of the company
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

But I think it's a wrong approach. Because when I want to list users of certain clients I can't do that. Also, where should I store the user role? Do I have to modify **auth_permission** table. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ForeignKey()` relationship for an user to client instead of `OneToOne`. For that either you extend django's `User` model or create your own user profile class.

To extend and add attributes in `User` model, refer [Extending User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

---

If you want to use django's built-in `User` model and authentication etc, better way is...

1. Create user profile model in your app with `OneToOne` relationship with `User`.
2. In this user profile model add specific information about users and relationship with other models. You can set role in this class and have `ForeignKey()` relation with `Client` model as you want many users for a client.

   class UserProfile(models.Model):
       client = models.ForiegnKey('Client')
       ...
3. Create the `UserProfile` instance for a user whenever new user is created.
4. Earlier, django had `user.get_profile()` method to get user profile object for user, but in 1.5.1 its deprecated.

Comment: I want to implement your second approach. But instead of creating another model `userProfile`, can't I just assume `Client` to be `UserProfile`.

Comment: @user2032220, you want many users for a client right, then you can't do that with `Client` as `UserProfile`

Comment: Ok thanks for that. But instead of `OnetoOne` if I do `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`, it can be done right.